# Create a Struct that receive a int value directly?

Tags: c#

I have a Struct in C# called `AddTwo`, where the idea is to receive an integer value and add two more:

```
namespace Struct
{
    struct AddTwo
    {
        public int Valor;

        public override int ToString()
        {
            return Valor + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

To call this class I am doing it as follows:

```
AddTwo x;
x.Valor = 10
Console.WriteLine(x);//The result is 12
```

As we know, the Struct type is a value type, and it works similarly (if not the same) to the value types we know like **int, double, float, string**...

In the case of these value types, we don't need to assign a value to an attribute as we are doing here: `x.Valor = 10;`, in their case, we can pass it directly in the Struct declaration like `x = 10;`.

How can I make Struct `AddTwo` work this way?

Comment: thats called an implicit conversion/cast operator - you can easily add them

Comment: @DanielA.White could you please make an example for me ?

Comment: Here are the docs for implicit (and explicit conversion): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Comment: The example says it all. Make a constuctor that takes the valor number, and make an implicit operator that uses that constructor: `public static implicit operator AddTwo(int valor) => new AddTwo(valor);`

Answer (score 0):

You can define struct like

```
public struct AddTwo 
{
 
        public AddTwo(int i)
        {
            Valor = i;
        }
        public int Valor;
        public static implicit operator AddTwo(int i)
        {
            return new AddTwo(i);
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (Valor + 2).ToString();
        }
}
```

now you can do this :

```
AddTwo s = 10;
Console.WriteLine(s); //output is 12
```

Comment: So... its no possible to create a Struct that I can pass a value without use a atribute? Like this X = 10; ?

Comment: @SudoSur no , in c# it's not possible

Comment: Sure you can. If the type of `X` is implicitly convertible from `int`, you definitely can say `X = 10;` As @daneilawhite pointed out, just read up on _implicit conversions_

Comment: @Flydog57 you are right i'm updating my answer

Comment: @SudoSur i updated correct answer please check it :)))

Answer (score 0):

To make the AddTwo struct work like other value types where you can assign the value directly without having to set the attribute, you can define a parameterized constructor that takes an integer value as a parameter and initializes the Valor field:

```
struct AddTwo
{
    public int Valor;

    public AddTwo(int valor)
    {
        Valor = valor;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (Valor + 2).ToString();
    }
}
```

AddTwo x = new AddTwo(10);

Console.WriteLine(x); // Output: 12

With this change, you can create an instance of AddTwo and initialize its Valor field in one step.